# Signal Proxy in GCP VM does not listen on port 80

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, firewall, iptables

I wanted to install a Signal proxy on Ubuntu VM in GCP.
I used the following:

https://github.com/gabyx/IranAProxy

```bash
./create-vm.sh
```

which creates the VM with a static global ip and http and https network firewall rules, basically this:

```bash
gcloud compute instances create "$VM_NAME" \
        --project=iranaproxy \
        --zone="$VM_ZONE" \
        --address="$externalIP" \
        --machine-type=e2-micro \
        --tags=http-server,https-server \
        --create-disk=auto-delete=yes,boot=yes,device-name=instance-1,image=projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-2204-jammy-v20221011,mode=rw,size=10,type=projects/iranaproxy/zones/me-west1-a/diskTypes/pd-balanced
```

which should already allow connections on port 80 and 443.

It will install the proxy as described [here](https://www.signal.org/blog/run-a-proxy)

https://github.com/gabyx/IranAProxy/blob/main/src/setup-proxy.sh
installes docker, clones https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-TLS-Proxy and runs `docker compose up`
and now I wanted to check if port 80 is open.

But with

```bash
nmap XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
```

I dont know, I thought the VM forwards all 80 and 443 ingress to the running docker containers ?

Anybody any help in achieving this, this mayhelp Iranian people...

Comment: COS forward ports. Compute Engine does not. For Compute Engine use the Docker -p flag to establish ports.

Comment: Isn't that what `docker compose` already does?
What is COS? Container-optimized OS? I use the ubunt 22.04, so no containried optimized os?

Comment: Your question needs details on what you have configured. Providing external links is OK for reference, but your question must be self-contained without requiring external links.

Comment: It turns out, the ports where already open, but the proxy did not startup and listen to the ports...which I could have guessed from the nmap output...